# Can I power up a Mac with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, mac, power, power-management, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini 2011 with Mac OS X X 10.7.5 and I want to power it on with a keyboard combination when it is off.

When the Mac is in sleep mode, you can just press a key or move the mouse to restore the OS X session, and you can not configure it from power management.

Is there a method for configuring sleep or powerup when it is off, or an external program?

Comment: The only way I know to turn on a mac is with the power key. There are a few ways to shut a mac down without the power key though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it's shut down. you cannot power on a Mac other than through the physical power button on the machine.

This used to be possible with the old [Apple Desktop Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Desktop_Bus) connections, and for a time when Apple shipped a special USB implementation with a power pin, but it was removed with the Apple Pro Keyboard (model M7803) in 2000.

Comment: Good, and it's possible configure stop mode for reactivate with a keyboard combination?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you need. You can wake up a sleeping Mac with any key. If that's not what you're asking, perhaps you can rephrase your question?

Comment: I want wake up mac from sleeping mode with a combination key configured from me.

Comment: No easy way I know of—you can just put it to sleep again after it's been woken up with the tool mentioned here: [Prevent a Mac from waking up from keyboard or mouse?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/prevent-a-mac-from-waking-up-from-keyboard-or-mouse)